# Can you CONCAT strings to form a Name Range for lookup value and then do Average?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to calculate the Average based on the Vlookup Values

In Sheet1 Column A I have options from drop-down list. All the options together form a Name Range called "TESTING"

[image]

In Sheet3 I have each option from drop-down list and corresponding values for vlookup

[image]

In Sheet2 when I run below Formula in which I specify my name range "TESTING" as lookup value I am able to calculate the Average. Please see below:

[image]

However when I use the CONCAT to concatenate values in column A & B to form lookup value (Name range - TESTING) for vlookup I get #N/A

[image]

Which is strange since the CONCAT on its own works fine

[image]

I've read that concatenating strings to form lookup value is possible. Am I doing something wrong here ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried in VLOOKUP `INDIRECT(CONCAT(A2,B2))`

Comment: I tend to use the & instead of concat() - less typing... INDIRECT(A2&B2)